# ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait

Tags: spring, grails, intellij-idea

I've converted a project from Grails 1.3.7 to 3.2.6.  I've worked through all of the errors that come out of `grails compile` as well as a ton of problems highlighted by IntelliJ.  Now, I'm trying to actually launch the app to see what I get, and I'm getting the error in the subject.

Here's the full stack/error:

```
    2017-06-02 07:45:16.650 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@70e659aa: startup date [Fri Jun 02 07:45:09 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at tbuilder326.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)

    2017-06-02 07:45:16.661 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in tbuilder326.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController] from plugin [springSecurityCore] : org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at tbuilder326.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController] from plugin [springSecurityCore] : org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController] from plugin [springSecurityCore] : org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:175)
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:104)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createBinaryGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:375)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:362)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:314)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:89)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:77)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:69)
        at tbuilder326.Application.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(Application.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:173)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing?  Some sort of compile or runtime dependency?

Comment: What version of spring security core?

Comment: It's version 3.2.0.M1

Comment: grisaf is right. You most switch to spring security core 3.1.2 you can read the reason here https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html in the 2.1. Installation section.

Thanks to sdelamo He noticed it here https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/495

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I switched to spring-security-core 3.1.2 and it was solved.

Comment: Switching to 3.1.2 does appear to have removed that error.