# Using graphql plugin in grails ends up with: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-orm, graphql

I try to make my 1st experience with graphql in the grails context.
I'm using:

jdk1.8.0_162

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

Build id: 20171218-0600

OS: Linux, v.4.4.0-116-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.18.9
Grails Version: 3.3.3

Groovy Version: 2.4.14

In build.gradle I entered the graphql-plugin via

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:gorm-graphql:1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
```

in the dependencies section. Starting grails ends up with build successful, run-up ends up in

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait
```

Any hints on Incompatibilities or missing entries in build.gradle?

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change dependency **from**

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:gorm-graphql:1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
```

**To**

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:converters:3.3.1'
```

OR

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:converters"
```

This is the Converters plugin that has been part of Grails core up until version 3.3 and now is a standalone plugin.

Users of Grails 3.3.x and above should use this plugin.

see plugin repository [here](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/converters/)

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but did not help

Comment: still: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328399/classnotfoundexception-org-grails-compiler-web-converters-renderconvertertrait

Comment: I tried with compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2" in my 
build.gradle dependencies,  but the error remains the same.

Comment: compile 'org.grails.plugins:converters:3.3.1' made the application work.

Comment: compile 'org.grails.plugins:converters' not found